# Edit text field data is not getting shared using intent

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-intent

I'm using an Edit text to save user input but not able to share the user data using intent. Please Help.

```
val editText = findViewById\<EditText?\>(R.id.textInput)
val text = editText.text.toString()
val shareButtonClick = findViewById<Button>(R.id.shareButton)
shareButtonClick.setOnClickListener {
    val textShare = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    textShare.type = "text/plain"
    textShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text)
    val chooser: Intent = Intent.createChooser(textShare,"Share via...") 
    Log.d("Shared Activity", "Entered text: $text")
    startActivity(chooser)
}      // intent chooser passed in startActivity
```

Comment: What type of intent operation is it, implicit or explicit intent ?

Comment: make sure you that the text is properly encoded if the text is not encoded correctly or the intent is missing the extra data type, then this problem will occur and the text will not be shared.

Comment: How can I do that?? I have used extra too.